# What top-like utility is this?

Tags: unix, top

I've seen this utility in a lot of tmux screenshots. What is it?

[image]

Source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be the [**`htop`**](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) utility.

Comment: Definitely htop. Available from http://htop.sourceforge.net/ and also in Ubuntu and Debian's standard repositories (and likely other distributions too): `aptitude install htop`.